# Find first buisness day of next month MySQL without function

Tags: mysql, date

We have a date_value column and another Boolean column which indicates whether the day is a business day or not.

We are trying to find the first business day of the next month( example, for September, 2015 I want it to return 2015-10-01)

We have tried a couple different methods involving last_day, intervals and subqueries but can't quite get it to work.

We also don't have the ability to create custom functions, which makes this a little more difficult.

Comment: What's this got to do with SQL?

Comment: Show what you tried. The solution is something like: finding the first day of the following month, finding what day of the week it is (from 1 to 7), and adding X days to find the first business day (X being the number of days until the following Monday). Good luck doing that with Mysql's date functions though.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand. We are looking for a way to do this in MySQL.

Comment: @rlanvin We are able to find the first day of next month using last_day(date_value) + interval 1 day. The problem is that sometimes that day (2014-06-01 in particular) lands on a weekend....

Comment: But why? MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of data. It's not a panacea.

Comment: @Strawberry because of the way our data is strucured. We have a snapshot table that calculates values but it has a day lag. Example would be today's record in the snapshot shows yesterday's data. We need to find values at the end of each month and being one day off is not an option in regards to accuracy. I recognize the restrictions of MySQL but this really is for the "retrieval of data" as we are using this to  do just that.

Comment: In that case consider providing sample data (and/or an sqlfiddle) and a desired result

Comment: @Strawberry looks like we were able to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select min(date_value) fwd
from tablename
where isWorkDay = 1 and
      extract(year from date_value)=extract(year from curdate()) and
      extract(month from date_value)=extract(month from curdate()) + 1
```

For all months (v0.3) (please note that I can test this now, so it might have some error):

```
select t1.month_number, min(t2.date_value)

from tablename t1 join
     tablename t2 on extract(year from t1.date_value) * 12 + t1.month_number = extract(year from t2.date_value) * 12 + t2.month_number - 1

where t2.isWorkDay = 1

group by t1.month_number
```

Comment: Thats right along the lines of what I'm looking at, and it works perfectly for the current month... problem is I need to apply it to each month historically... currently working on a modification, but if you have one off the top of your head, I would be must appreciative.

Comment: Were do you get the "current month"? From date_value?

Comment: yes, I've been using month(date_value). We also have a month_number column

Comment: You're edit, works for a single year, but doesn't cross over. I like it much better than mine though and so ill switch over to testing and modifying yours as opposed to my behemoth

Comment: Yes you're right. It still needs some tweaking. I forgot January is after December :-)

Comment: I think now it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it using the below

```
SELECT
d.year
,d.month_number
,first_business_period as next_month_first_period
,d2.previous_business_day
FROM lk_date d
    JOIN (
    SELECT
        a.*
        , MAX(CASE WHEN d2.business_period_in_days<>0 THEN d2.date_value ELSE NULL END) AS previous_business_day
    FROM(
    SELECT
                d1.year
                ,d1.month_number
                , MIN(CASE WHEN d1.business_period_in_days <> 0 THEN d1.date_value END) AS first_business_period
    FROM lk_date d1
    GROUP BY 1,2
        ) a
    JOIN lk_date d2 ON d2.date_Value < a.first_business_period
    GROUP BY 1,2,3) d2 on d2.previous_business_day = d.date_value
```